# Why is my list equal check not working when they look the same in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, equality

Part of my Flutter program creates a list and later checks to see if the list is equal to another.  However, when I test this, it returns false.  I've done a series of printout statements to check why they aren't equal and they look the same, but it keeps returning false.

The code:

```
print("programList: " + programList.toString());
//print(programList.runtimeType);
var testResult = (programList == ["apple", "apple", "banana"]);
print("programList are correct: " + testResult.toString());
for(var i in programList){
  print(i + ": " + i.runtimeType);
}
if(programList == ["apple", "apple", "banana"]){
  print("in test loop");
  //do stuff
}
```

This is the print out:

```
I/flutter ( 1429): programList: \[apple, apple, banana\]
I/flutter ( 1429): programList are correct: false

Exception caught by gesture
The following \_TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '\_Type' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'other'
```

The error didn't start showing up until the runtimeType for loop, but before that, it didn't print "in test loop".

I tried adding all of those print statements to see what was happening.  I tried adding runtimeTypes to try to understand if they were coming up with different types, but that caused an error of it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dart's default is to compare the objects by `reference`. As the result, you have different references for 2 arrays with the same values.

To make it work you have to use `DeepCollectionEquality`

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  Function equality = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
  final programList = ["apple", "apple", "banana"];
  print(equality(programList, ["apple", "apple", "banana"]));
}
```

Comment: It's coming up with an error on DeepCollectionEquality().equals.  It says that it isn't a class.  Is there some sort of import statement that I need?  I can't seem to find one in the Flutter api docs

Comment: add import: import 'package:collection/collection.dart';